# Two Uart not occurred interrupt in same time in stm32

Tags: c, embedded

I am working on the STM32f407 controller. I am using uart2 and uart3 in receive interrupt mode.
The first time only I got interrupted on uart3 after that only I got data on uart2. I am not getting interrupted on uart3.
Below is my code:-

I am getting interrupted in uart2 only.

Please tell me if I am doing ant=y thing wrong.

Comment: void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
 if(huart2.Instance == USART2)
 {
  gsm.RxData[gsm.RxDataCnt]=Uart_Rx_Buffer;
  gsm.RxDataCnt=(1+ gsm.RxDataCnt) % MAX_Buff_Size;
  HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2,&Uart_Rx_Buffer, 1);
 }
 else if(huart3.Instance == USART3)
 {
  lidar.RxData[lidar.RxDataCnt]=uart3_RX_Data;
  lidar.RxDataCnt=(1+ lidar.RxDataCnt) % MAX_LIDAR_BUFFER;
  HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart3,&uart3_RX_Data, 1);
  if(lidar.RxDataCnt >MAX_COUNT_BUFFER)
  {
   lidar.received = true;
  }
 }
}

Comment: Post the code inside the question with code formatting, not as a comment.

Comment: Post the initialization code too, not just callback.

Comment: void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
 if(huart2.Instance == USART2)
 {
  gsm.RxData[gsm.RxDataCnt]=Uart_Rx_Buffer;
  gsm.RxDataCnt=(1+ gsm.RxDataCnt) % MAX_Buff_Size;
  HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2,&Uart_Rx_Buffer, 1);
 }
 else if(huart3.Instance == USART3)
 {
  lidar.RxData[lidar.RxDataCnt]=uart3_RX_Data;
  lidar.RxDataCnt=(1+ lidar.RxDataCnt) % MAX_LIDAR_BUFFER;
  HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart3,&uart3_RX_Data, 1);
  if(lidar.RxDataCnt >MAX_COUNT_BUFFER)
  {
   lidar.received = true;
  }
 }
}

Comment: There is a link called "edit" below the post, use that one. In the future, don't run off to post a new question, but fix the one you've posted instead.